# How to move Y axis on highchart

Tags: highcharts

[image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in5UD.png)

Hello, i have a question about HighCharts.
I would like to ask how to move the y-axis to the right side of the chart and make the "bars" point to the left instead of the default right. like on screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Set `opposite` property to `'right'` and correct labels positions by `x` and `y` properties.

For example:

```
  yAxis: {
    ...,
    opposite: 'right',
    labels: {
      align: 'right',
      y: -4,
      x: 0
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/s1tfezL6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis